# Ruby - Opening absolute url from relative

Tags: ruby, url, nokogiri, relative-path, open-uri

I've built a web scraper ruby script using open-uri and nokogiri, I'm pretty new to it all but it's all working for a couple of the websites I need to extract data from that have full URL's in the source, apart from one which uses relative URL's.

What the script does, is opens the page, builds an array of pages to open then goes through and extracts the data from the css (not xpath).

How do I force the script to use full URL's in the instance where they're relative, it's been bugging me for a while and I can't seem to get it running

In my case, I think I need to add something at the point it pushes the URL's, could anyone please point me in the right direction? It would be hugely appreciated! Thanks!

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.OMMITED.co.uk"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL, "User-Agent" => “OMMITED“))

links = page.css("a")

links_array = Array.new

links.each{|link|
        url = link['href'].nil? ? 'empty' : link['href']
        if url.include? 'category'  and !url.include? '/all'
                links_array.push url
        end
}
```

Comment: You could use a regex to check for a fully qualified URL, something like /^[\w]*:\/\// - if it matches then prepend the root URL. Remembering the subtlety of '/' at the start of a relative URL denoting that it starts at the root of the path after the server, as opposed to relative links starting without a slash, which match the directory of the current page. I'd write an answer but I'd need more knowledge of the variables available to me. (The current fully qualified URL and the current page path, mainly.)

Comment: Edited to add variables!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: Short answer at bottom.

OK, assuming you have a class variable called `@url` containing the fully qualified URL of the current page:

```
require 'uri'

def full_url(rel, url)
  return rel if rel.match /^[\w]*:\/\//
  uri = URI(url)
  if rel[0] == '/'
    "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}#{rel}"
  else
    path = uri.path.split('/')[0..-2].select{|m| !m.empty?}.join('/')
    "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}/#{path}/#{rel}"
  end
end
```

Then you can call:

```
links_array.push full_url(url, @url)
```

You can put the method in the same class or in a helper class somewhere. It uses the Ruby URI library to find the relevant parts of the fully qualified URL, then constructs a new one from the relative path.

If the relative path starts with '/' it should come straight after the host.

If it doesn't start with a '/' then it needs to be in the same virtual directory as the current page. Thus, if the current page is:

```
http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ccc
```

and the relative path is:

```
ddd
```

then the output should be:

```
http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ddd
```

however, if the relative path is:

```
/ddd
```

then the output should be:

```
http://www.host.com/ddd
```

The code:

```
uri.path.split('/')[0..-2].select{|m| !m.empty?}.join('/')
```

takes the path of the full URL, splits it on '/' giving an array (`['aaa','bbb', 'ccc']`), then removes the last element. (`['aaa','bbb']`). The select removes any blank elements then the join stitches it up again. (`"aaa/bbb"`)

OR

you could do it the boring way:

```
require 'uri'

URI.join("http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ccc", "/ddd").to_s
# => "http://www.host.com/ddd" 

URI.join("http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ccc", "ddd").to_s
# => "http://www.host.com/aaa/bbb/ddd"
```

given your code:

```
links.each{|link|
    url = link['href'].nil? ? 'empty' : link['href']
    if url.include? 'category'  and !url.include? '/all'
            links_array.push url
    end
}
```

I would re-write as:

```
links.each do |link|
  url = link['href'].nil? ? 'empty' : link['href']
  if url.include? 'category' && !url.include? '/all'
    full_url = URI.join(PAGE_URL, url).to_s 
    puts full_url
    links_array << url
    puts links_array.inspect
  end
end
```

Note: Stylistically, multi-line blocks should use do/end rather than {}. Indents should be two spaces. There shouldn't be spaces just inside parentheses. The << operator is favoured over push. Always use && in conditionals rather than `and`, which has a far lower precedence and can cause issues. See the Github style guide:

https://github.com/styleguide/ruby

The `puts` are there based on your comments, hopefully helping you figure out why your array isn't behaving. As it should be, based on the code you put in there. I'd prefer to use the debugger gem though. (Or byebug if you're on Ruby 2.x)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've added your code and added an @url variable which has resulted in stopping the No such file or directory error, which I think indicates it's putting the two values together but it doesn't seem to be opening the URL array which I'll need to look into, I'll try and fix that and come back to confirm that your resolution works! Thanks!

Comment: Check the edited end of the answer, which shows a far simpler and cleaner solution.

Comment: Inspired by your last comment, I've come up with this 
`code`
@full_url = URI.join( PAGE_URL, url ).to_s

puts @full_url
                        links_array.push @full_url
                end
}
`code`
It's joining correctly (the puts is printing full URL's) but it doesn't look like it's passing to the array. Can you see any errors here that could explain that?

Comment: I'll update the question, bear with me. In the meantime, use `[]` to initialize an array: `my_array = []` rather than `my_array = Array.new`. We are not coding Java. ;) Also, you can use backticks around the code you want highlighted in comments, rather than around the word 'code'. :)

Comment: Answer updated, although I can't see an issue - apart from the stylistic issues I mentioned.

Comment: Haha, when you dabble in a few languages but are a master of none things can get crossed! I've updated and can print my array so all is working, thanks very much for your help!